# cs50 PSET6/DNA Regular Expressions

Tags: python, regex, cs50

I'm attempting to work through finding the amount of consecutive STRs (a substring pattern, i.e. "AGAT") in a sequence file.

String Patterns: AGATC,TTTTTTCT,AATG,TCTAG,GATA,TATC,GAAA,TCTG

Sequence file(one of many other sequence files): AAGGTAAGTTTAGAATATAAAAGGTGAGTTAAATAGAATAGGTTAAAATTAAAGGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCAGAAAAGAGTAAATAGTTAAAGAGTAAGATATTGAATTAATGGAAAATATTGTTGGGGAAAGGAGGGATAGAAGG

In the above sequence, TATC is the maximum with a run of 5 consecutive TATC pairs.  With my regular expression, it is returning matches whether they are consecutive or not.

I believe using regular expressions is my best bet.  This is my first time working in Python so don't expect too much.  I've used the regex tool at regex101.com and it has provided me some good insight into regex formulations. I'm passing a variable into the regex with {head}, which which is the string pattern, but I want to find the matched string `{head}` 2 or more times.  My below regex returns a match to `head` at least 1 or more times, so I know why that is returning the way it does.

```
groups = re.findall(rf'?:{head})+, text)
```

If I use `r"(AGAT){2,}"` in regex101.com, this works the way I expect.  It finds the matched string of characters 2 or more times.  If I pass it into my code as `groups = re.findall(rf'(?:{head}){2,})`, it doesn't return anything.

My code is below:

```
import csv
import re
import string


if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("missing command-line argument")
    exit(1)

if re.search(r"(.csv)", sys.argv[1]) == None:
    print("CSV file not found!")
    print("Usage: 'python.py *.csv *.txt'")
    exit(1)

if re.search(r"(.txt)", sys.argv[2]) == None:
    print("TXT file not found!")
    print("Usage: 'python.py *.csv *.txt'")
    exit(1)

# use reader or DictReader from the CSV module
# use sys.argv for command-line arguments
# use open(filename) and f.read() to read its contents.

# open CSV and DNA sequence and read into memory
with open(sys.argv[1], newline='') as database, open(sys.argv[2], newline='') as sequence:
    reader = csv.DictReader(database)
    headers = reader.fieldnames
    text = sequence.read()
    for head in headers:
        groups = re.findall(rf'(?:{head})+', text)
        print(head, groups)
```

If I use the above `groups = re.findall(rf'(?:{head})+', text)` variable I get the below output

```
AGATC ['AGATCAGATCAGATCAGATC']
TTTTTTCT []
AATG ['AATG']
TCTAG []
GATA ['GATA', 'GATA']
TATC ['TATCTATCTATCTATCTATC']
GAAA ['GAAA', 'GAAA', 'GAAA']
TCTG []
```

If I use `groups = re.findall(rf'(?:{head}){2,}', text)` I get nothing.

```
AGATC []
TTTTTTCT []
AATG []
TCTAG []
GATA []
TATC []
GAAA []
TCTG []
```

So, I suppose I'm asking, how can I use regex to find a string of characters(passed as a variable) 2 or more times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was given from a user, yeahIProgram, on Reddit's cs50 subreddit.

```
"That's what I was referring to, but I had to look it up and you escape the braces inside the formatted string by doubling them."
```

So, the regular expression I was looking for was `groups = re.findall(rf'(({head}){{2,}})', text)`.  Which in returned the below output that I was expecting.

```
AGATC [('AGATCAGATCAGATCAGATC', 'AGATC')]
TTTTTTCT []
AATG []
TCTAG []
GATA []
TATC [('TATCTATCTATCTATCTATC', 'TATC')]
GAAA []
TCTG []
```

Now, I just need to get the total number of times the string occurs and I should be well on my.

Thank you @Andrej Kesely for your input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pattern `((your pattern)\2*)` in your regular expression to find largest consecutive pattern ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/G3HaBo/1) for pattern `TATC`):

```
import re

seq = 'AAGGTAAGTTTAGAATATAAAAGGTGAGTTAAATAGAATAGGTTAAAATTAAAGGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCAGAAAAGAGTAAATAGTTAAAGAGTAAGATATTGAATTAATGGAAAATATTGTTGGGGAAAGGAGGGATAGAAGG'
patterns = ['AGATC','TTTTTTCT','AATG','TCTAG','GATA','TATC','GAAA','TCTG']

m = max([x for p in patterns for x in re.findall(r'(({})\2*)'.format(p), seq)], key=lambda k: len(k[0]) // len(k[1]))
print('Most repeated pattern: {}, number of repetitions {}'.format(m[1], len(m[0]) // len(m[1])))
```

Prints:

```
Most repeated pattern: TATC, number of repetitions 5
```

Comment: I attempted `groups = re.findall(rf'(?:{head})\2*'` and I found myself with quite a few errors.  I could place the string patterns in an array, but the challenge we're given has those patterns as headers in a CSV file that we need to pull out.  Which is why I need to keep it as a variable.

Comment: I've tried both suggestions `groups = re.findall(rf'(?:{head})\1*', text)` and `groups = re.findall(rf'(?:{head})\2*', text)` and both are returning errors.  Below:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dna.py", line 31, in <module>
    STRs = re.compile(rf'(?:{head})\2*')
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py", line 399, in _escape
    raise source.error("invalid group reference %d" % group, len(escape) - 1)
re.error: invalid group reference 2 at position 9

Comment: unfortunately, I'm still throwing errors.  
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dna.py", line 31, in <module>
    groups = re.findall(rf'((?{head})\2*)', text)
re.error: unknown extension ?n at position 2
```

Comment: @Rsp8 Try it without the `?`: `groups = re.findall(rf'(({head})\2*)', text)` -> as I have it in my answer.

Comment: @Anrej Kesley, that seemed to work, however, rather than returning only 1 string of characters, it returns multiple.
```AGATC [('AGATCAGATCAGATCAGATC', 'AGATC')]
TTTTTTCT []
AATG [('AATG', 'AATG')]
TCTAG []
GATA [('GATA', 'GATA'), ('GATA', 'GATA')]
TATC [('TATCTATCTATCTATCTATC', 'TATC')]
GAAA [('GAAA', 'GAAA'), ('GAAA', 'GAAA'), ('GAAA', 'GAAA')]
TCTG []
```
I just need the longest consecutive.  I'll keep playing around with it.